# Complement of the complete bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

Hey taking the complement of the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ I think that I get a disconnected graph composed of the complete graph $K_m$ and the complete graph $K_n$ is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The $m$ vertices are not connected to each other in $K_{m,n}$, so $K_m$ forms in the complement, and along similar lines of reasoning, $K_n$ is in the complement also. However they are not connected since the $m$ vertices and $n$ vertices are all connected to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the help and for editing the question.